# Gesture detector with scroll view in android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement `Webview` with scroll view to detect gesture detector from swipe left to right and right to left how to do? can anybody give example

Answer (score 3):

`WebView` already scrolls, so you do not need the `ScrollView`.

`WebView` already handles swipes to move left and right, so you do not need the gesture detector.

Hence, your solution is just a plain `WebView`.